# Django, url configuration reverse question. Gives ImproperConfigured

Tags: django, settings

I tried to use this 2 lines to check if url reverse works...:
    from django.urls import reverse
    reverse('country-autocomplete')
It suppose to give me:
    u'/country-autocomplete/'
I did this earlier and it worked perfectly, since I had couple of problems and did couple of changes in environment(?).

Now I'm trying to run these commands in cmd->python with swthed on environment and it gives me this fault:

```
>>> from django.urls import reverse
>>> reverse('raildict-autocomplete')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\me\Envs\sc_project\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py", line 31, in reverse
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)
  File "C:\Users\me\Envs\sc_project\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 69, in get_resolver
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
  File "C:\Users\me\Envs\sc_project\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\me\Envs\sc_project\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

What have I done to break it, and probably the most important how to fix it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is kind of dumb...

I fired up: 'python' from cmd

and then:

```
>>>from django.urls import reverse
>>>reverse('sch-autocomplete')
```

But, it is not supposed to be done that way and sure it gave me the fault message. Oh! I was so sad! But it is only my mistake, thanks goodness... Environment is good, paths are good and etc. Just have to do it right way:

```
python manage.py shell
>>>from django.urls import reverse
>>>reverse('sch-autocomplete')
```

And after it gave me right reverse path. I will leave it here... Because I saw very in deep, complicated answers on:  Requested setting ROOT_URLCONF, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
But the problem in my code was on the suface and only because I did wrong coding in cmd. May be it helps to somebody and saves the time...

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('src:post')
```

Was having this kind of error it tired this and my error solved
This provides default revers after a operations performed

or you are reversing to path that is having an issue or that doesn't exist.
or use reverse_lazy.

Comment: That is a really frustrating mistake... I didn't have it earlier... I have the same code, I had before... It didn't give me any trouble, but after trying out, django_filters and some pip install for bootstrap forms (cannot find it right now) and after uninstalling them... Now I constantly have this mistake, doesn't matter how I change my code. I tried to change the absolute path for reverse, din't work, path has to be ok, because it worked before just fine. Feels like environment got screwed somehow.. Thank you for help!

Comment: I also have these kind of mistakes all over the place right now: GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found) ----As I understand it tells me that I don't have autocomplete light installed... It is installed and I reinstalled it again...